# Offline map navigation Java or Python

Tags: java, python, routes, raspberry-pi, navigation

So I am doing this project for my motorbike.
Long story short I need a way where I can download maps locally and navigate them.

I have a GPS module that can feed in the current data, but no internet connectivity. I am planning to run it on a PI zero W. So I am aware of Open Street Maps, but I can't find an open source / free routing library. Perhaps I am just missing something. Any help is appreciated.